# Digit sum of $9^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

> Let $n>2$ be an integer. Prove that the digit sum of $9^n$ is greater than $9$.

My starting approach was to observe that $9^n$ either ends in $1$ or $9$. If it ends in $9$ then the result is obvious. If it ends in $1$, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The digit sum must be divisible by $9$, and it clearly cannot be $0$. Your job is to show that it isn't $9$ either.

Comment: Oops!  I thought ‘power of $3’ Sorry… I'll remove my comment.

Comment: I mis-read your question :)! At least it can be shown that the digit-sum must be $\geq 9$; a reason is as follows:

Comment: Since
$$
9^{n} = a_{m}10^{m} + a_{m-1}10^{m-1} + \cdots + a_{1}
$$
for some integer $m \geq 2$ and some integers $1 \leq a_{1},\dots, a_{m} \leq 9$,
consider the real polynomial
$$
f(x) := a_{m}x^{m} + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_{1}.
$$
By the division and remainder theorems there is some real polynomial $q(x)$ such that
$$
f(x) = (x-1)q(x) + f(1);
$$
hence
$$
f(10) = 9^{n} = 9q(10) + \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{k}.
$$
This implies that the sum on the right-hand side (i.e. your digit-sum) of the previous equality must be divisible by $9$
and hence $\geq 9$.

Comment: An interesting observation: It seems that for every value of $k$, there is a value of $n$ such that the sum of the last $k$ digits of $9^n$ is **not** greater than $9$. Meaning, this question cannot be solved by considering a partial suffix of $9^n$ (i.e., $9^n\bmod10^k$, which is how I approached this problem). A very interesting question indeed!!!

Comment: Very  nice question, by the way. It's difficult, and I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this can be shown by generalising the argument in the question and checking lots of cases. Assume for contradiction that the digit sum of $9^n$ is $9$. Then either $9^n < 100000$, or the following three properties hold.

- The digit sum of $9^n \% 100000$ is less than 9
- The digit sum of $9^n \% 99999$ is exactly 9
- The last digit of $9^n \% 99999$ is not zero

where $9^n\%d$ means the least non-negative residue of $9^n$ modulo $d$.

[This Python code](https://repl.it/DK2c/3) checks $n \leq 7501$, after which the pairs $(n\%100000, n\%99999)$ start repeating with period 7500. It shows that there are no $n$ for which the three properties all hold.

Comment: I'm hoping for a more illuminating answer; but I think you're right. Yet what's lacking here for me is a proof that your proposed period of 7500 holds for $9^n$ for all $n$. From similar experiments, it seems that $a_0$ has an observed period $2$, $a_1$ has an observed period $10$, and for $k>1$, it seems that $a_k$ has an observed period of $10^k/2$ (where $a_k$ is the $k$-th digit of $9^n$). But I don't yet have a proof for those results, other than 'well, it sure looks that way, because a quick and dirty Python program says so up to pretty freaking large $n$'. Unsatisfying as a proof!

Comment: Why did you choose the specific value of $100000$?

Comment: @ChasBrown: the periodicity follows from $9^{7501}$ being congruent to $9$ modulo $99999$, and also congruent to $9$ modulo $100000$. This can be checked independently, for example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E7501+modulo+99999*100000)

Comment: @barakmanos: I tried a few variants and these are the values that worked

Comment: @Colin : Well, that is then proof enough for me! :)