# For every $k$ there exists $n$ such that the sum of the last $k$ digits of $9^n$ is $\leq9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1911009/131263), which asks for a proof about the digit sum of $9^n$ being greater than $9$.

I have conducted some experiments while trying (and miserably failing) to prove it.

My initial approach was to show that it is sufficient to consider some partial suffix of $9^n$.

But it seems that however long I choose the suffix to be, there is always some value of $n$ for which the digit sum of the suffix of $9^n$ is **NOT** greater than $9$.

In other words, $\forall_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\exists_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\text{digit sum of }9^n\bmod10^k\leq9$.

Although it will not answer the original question, how can I go about proving this observation?

Comment: Let $n$ be the order of $9 \pmod {10^k}$.  Then your sum is $1$...

Comment: @lulu: Brilliant (!!!), thanks.

Comment: @lulu: I guess, if you could say something about the prefix (i.e., the first $k$ digits) of $9^n$, then you would possibly be able to prove the original question...

Comment: Isn't there some ergodic style argument to show that we can make the prefix anything we want?

Comment: @lulu: Well, I don't see how this would help proving that the digit sum of $9^n$ is greater than $9$ for every $n>2$.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  Yes...there is an argument of that form, but it doesn't help since the goal is to show something about all powers of $9$.

Comment: Crossed emails.  But, yes.  Your objection is spot on.

Comment: @lulu: Hahaha, "crossed emails" as in two people sending messages to each other at the same time? That's a new one :)

Comment: I have given an alternative answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to write $9^{2n}$ as
$$81^n=(80+1)^n$$
whose last terms when expanded are
$$\dots+512000\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6+6400\frac{n(n-1)}2+80n+1$$
All we have to do is make $n=k!10^k$ for $k$ as large as we want and we are guaranteed to have $81^n$ end in $\underbrace{00\dots0}_{k-1}1$, this suffix digit sum obviously being 1.

Comment: I like this answer, but isn't it sufficient to have $n = 10^k$ to get $k$ zeroes?

Comment: @Turambar I include the factorial so as to ensure that it divides the $k!$ in the denominator of the binomial coefficient. That way nothing is left to divide the $10^k$ part by, and I am guaranteed the desired suffix.

Comment: I think it works out alright. $$(80+1)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}80^i = 80^n + 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!i!}80^i$$ $$ = 80^n + 1 + n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-i)!i!}80^i = 80^n + 1 + n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i}80^i$$

Comment: Since $\gcd(9,10)=1$, the answer proposed by @lulu in a comment (choose $n=$ order of $9\pmod{10^k}$) seems sufficient. This answer also works. Thank you.